# Implementing C-like assert

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement an assert function.  How can I get the text of the failing condition into the error message?  If I have to parse it from the backtrace, can I portably rely on anything about the format of frames?

Comment: You do know that `assert` exists in Python?

Comment: @delnan I *think* he's asking how to get the specific details of an `AssertionError`., i.e why it failed

Comment: Looks to me like xe's trying to implement it from scratch.

Comment: If my_assert(x == 0) should fail, the error message should include 'x == 0'.  Apologies if this was unclear.

Comment: `assert x==0, "x==0"`

Comment: Code like that tickles my DRY sense, even if it's a fairly harmless case. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure the expression to test is secure you could do something like this:

File my_assert.py:

```
import sys

def my_assert(condition):
    caller = sys._getframe(1)
    if not eval(condition, caller.f_globals, caller.f_locals):
        raise AssertionError(repr(condition) + " on line " +
                             str(caller.f_lineno) + ' in ' +
                             caller.f_code.co_name)
```

File test_my_assert.py:

```
from my_assert import my_assert

global_var = 42

def test():
    local_var = 17
    my_assert('local_var*2 < global_var') # OK
    my_assert('local_var > global_var')

test()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_my_assert.py", line 10, in <module>
    test()
  File "test_my_assert.py", line 8, in test
    my_assert('local_var > global_var')
  File "my_assert.py", line 8, in my_assert
    caller.f_code.co_name)
AssertionError: 'local_var > global_var' on line 8 in test
```

Answer (score 3):

AssertionError is just like any other exception in python, and `assert` is a simple statement that is equivalent to

```
if __debug__:
    if not expression: raise AssertionError
```

or

```
if __debug__:
    if not expression1: raise AssertionError(expression2)
```

so you can add a second parameter to your assertion to have additional output

```
from sys import exc_info
from traceback import print_exception
# assertions are simply exceptions in Python
try:
    assert False, "assert was false"
except AssertionError:
    print_exception(*exc_info())
```

outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AssertionError: assert was false
```

Comment: Or, to put it another way, Python isn't C and it's usually not a great idea to try to make it look like C.  If you want to print or log something about an assertion failure, catch AssertionError (as shown) and use the traceback facilities.  You can use `except AssertionError as err:` and inspect `err.message` and/or `err.args` to see if there was a second argument.  (A missing second argument results in err.message being an empty string an err.args being a zero-element tuple.)

Comment: (Also, minor item: that should be `print_exception(*exc_info())` in the code sample above.)

Comment: and that's a very good point as well, I generally recommend against assertions anyway, but doing it like this is certainly unnecessarily messy.

The crux was really just to illustrate that adding a second "argument" to assert gives the exception a textual output (like `raise AssertionError("error")`)

Answer (score 0):

My very hackish solution:

```
def my_assert(condition):
    if not eval(condition):
        # error stuff
```

Then use it by placing the condition in quotation marks. It is then a string that can be printed in the error message.

Or, if you want it to actually raise an `AssertionError`:

```
def my_assert(condition):
    if not eval(condition):
        raise AssertionError(condition)
```

Comment: That fails as soon as `condition` uses local variables. If the definition of `my_assert` is in a different module than the call, it doesn't even permit referring to globals (that includes modules, functions, classes, etc. imported/defined at module level).